# Parallelogram Ratios

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a parallelogram. Let M be the midpoint of AB and N be the midpoint of AD. Diagonal BD intersects CM and CN at P and Q, respectively. Find PQ/BD.

Can this be solved using similar triangles?

Comment: What is your idea? Please explain in details.

Comment: When drawing my diagram, I tried drawing a segment from N to M. That creates triangle CMN. So I then tried to find the relationship between triangle CMN and triangle CPQ.

Comment: Besides using similar triangles, you need to apply the knowledge of  the centroid of a triangle too.

Comment: There's a nice technique using the centroid; but not much in the way of similar triangles is required there, I think.

Comment: Is Point P and Point Q the centroid? I know that the centroid is the intersection of the medians. However, I'm looking at the diagonal BD and since the diagonals don't necessarily bisect each other, I can't figure out how to apply what I know about centroids.

Comment: 1) The diagonals (AC and BD cut at X) of a parallelogram must bisect each other. This is one of the properties of parallelogram. 2) DQX and CQN are the medians of triangle ACD such that Q is the centroid of triangle ACD. Thus, CQ:QN = 2:1. 3) That ratio will be sufficient for comparing the lengths of MN, PQ, BD. 4) P is also the centroid of triangle ABC. However, just Q will be sufficient. 5) As pointed out, using centroid method may not fit your requirement (but is faster for me).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can be solved by similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

The lines BD and MN divide the diagonal AC into three pieces. You could find the relative proportions of those three pieces, and then by choosing appropriate similar triangles you can find the desired ratio.